# Moving the location of x and y axis to remove space in the plot

Tags: ggplot2, plot, axis, axis-labels

I am attempting to plot some data at depth using ggplot2. I have successfully flipped my axes to how I would like it, I just have three small issues I am unable to resolve.

I have attached an image of my plot with three different coloured circles showing my issues[Graph with current issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oVvc.jpg):

1. (Red Circle) Firstly, I do not know how to reduce the space between the beginning of the graph and the 0cm Depth so the first value of my data is plotted at the beginning of the plot space. In addition, please may I ask how I ensure that 0% Loss on ignition is plotted on the x axis?
2. (Blue Circle) Please may I ask how I ensure that 75% Loss on ignition is plotted also on the x axis?
3. (Green Circle) Please may I ask how I reduce the empty space at the bottom of the plot where no data is found?

Below is my attached code that I have used to create the plot:
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

```
Lovojarvi <- ggplot(LovLOI2, aes(x = `Depth (cm)`, y = `LOI (%)`)) +
  geom_line(color = "red", size = 1, linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(x = `Depth (cm)`, y = `LOI (%)`)) +
  scale_x_reverse(LovLOI$`Depth (cm)`)+ #reverse depth so it starts at zero
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Depth (cm)", breaks = seq(0,260,20))+
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right", breaks = seq(0,75,5)) +
  labs(x = "Depth (cm)", y = "Loss on ignition (%)")+
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0,75))+
  coord_flip(xlim = c(260,0))#this is how you reverse the look and order or the coordinates for the graph. The order of the y lim matters! the vector must be ordered first value last value
#View(Lovojarvi) #views the attributes associated with the image
ggsave("LovojarviLOI.png", Lovojarvi, width = 6, height = 10) #save the plot. can edit the width and height here.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best wishes
Leeza

I did try using the ggsave function in the above code to edit the plot space. I have also tried to define the breaks for both the x and y axis and the start and end value but they are not being plotted on one of the axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some simulated data, here's a few tweaks which hopefully gives you what you need. This is mostly achieved by:

- `expand = expansion(0)` will add 0 space to the top and bottom of the axes
- `limits = c(0, 75)` within `scale_y_continuous` will ensure it goes all the way up to 75

I've condensed a few lines not needed also, and suggested a way of formatting your top axis as %s. Hope that's helpful!

```r
library(tidyverse)

LovLOI <- tibble(depth = seq(0, 260, 2),
                 loss = runif(131, 0, 74))

LovLOI |>
  ggplot(aes(x = depth, y = loss)) +
  geom_line(color = "red",
            linewidth = 1,
            linetype = 2) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_reverse(name = "Depth (cm)",
                  breaks = seq(0, 260, 20),
                  expand = expansion(0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    "Loss on ignition (%)",
    position = "right",
    breaks = seq(0, 75, 5),
    expand = expansion(0),
    limits = c(0, 75),
    labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

As a brief follow-up, have a look at how `expansion` works - it takes arguments for `mult` and `add` and you can use either to set how much you want to expand the limits of the axis. By giving it two values, e.g. `mult = c(0, 0.01)` it will expand the bottom of the axis by `0` and the top by `0.01` * the maximum value. You can use this to eliminate space at 0s and control the space at the tops of each axis.